# Does Realm offer undo/redo like CoreData?

Tags: ios, realm

I was wondering if anyone knows whether or not Realm (https://realm.io/) offers the equivalence of undo/redo like Core Data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About a year ago, [this post](http://bsktapp.com/blog/why-is-realm-great-and-why-are-we-not-using-it/) mentioned one of the reasons they are still using CoreData is the presence of *undo* in CoreData. Members of the Realm team haven't addressed this issue yet, but the current version does not contain this functionality.

It has been raised as a feature request [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1572).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer